# Unable to open Javascript file in Eclipse getting the below error

Tags: javascript, eclipse

[image]

Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0)

Comment: Were you intending to use an external editor?

Comment: yes, by mistake while creating a js file in eclipse. no i need to revert it.

Comment: please suggest to revert it back

Comment: I think that's a bug in the wizard. You should be able to right-click on a file and open it with the Generic Text Editor the rest of the time.